# Is there a way of computing numerical integration on PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I've got a table with the following columns: `timestamp`, `name` and `activePower`. I wanted to compute power consumption based on that and add it to a Grafana line chart.

Right now, what I'm doing is a cumulative sum, like the following:

```sql
SELECT
  "timestamp" as time,
  "name", sum("activePower")
    OVER(
      PARTITION BY "name"
      ORDER BY "timestamp"
    ) AS cumulative_sum
FROM   main
```

Unfortunately, the intervals of `timestamp` are not regular, and I wanted to do something like a numerical integration (using trapezoidal rule or something).

Comment: You could join adjacent rows and then multiply the difference of the timestamps with the active power. Exact computation depends on the semantics of your records. Trapezoidal should be something like multiplying the average of both active powers with the length of the timestamp interval. So in general: This is possible, use ```JOIN``` for it and operate on the intervals

Comment: You can multiply by using the `*` operator. You can summate by using the `SUM()` aggregate function. And you probably need the `lag()` window function, too!

Comment: I think it's perfectly possible. Please add a few rows of sample data to your question, and also the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and sums.  Something like this:

```
select m.*,
       sum( (extract(epoch from timestamp) - extract(epoch from prev_timestamp)) * (activePower + prev_activePower) / 2 ) as activePower_seconds
from (select m.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by name order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp,
             lag(activePower) over (partition by name order by activePower) as prev_activePower
      from main m
     ) m;
```

This does the integral using seconds for the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 2):

Although is marked as correct, the second line:

```
lag(activePower) over (partition by name order by activePower)
```

Should be ordered by timestamp too.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30905533)